# Android use MenuItem to hide LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am new on android.
What I want to do is, when I press the icon on Actionbar the LinearLayout is showing.

Here's the picture 
[image]

As you can see, there's a magnifier icon.
when I press that icon, the search bar below it will gone.
And when i press the icon again, it'll show again.

I already trying use setVisibility, but its show error.

Here's my Java code

```
MenuItem searchBar;

    searchBar = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.search);
    searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

 public void toggle_contents(View v){

      if(searchBar.isShown()){
        Fx.slide_up(this, searchBar);
        searchBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }
      else{
        searchBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fx.slide_down(this, searchBar);
      }
}
```

And Here's my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:background="@color/gray74"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="7dip"
    android:paddingBottom="7dip" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/search_global"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbackground"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="@color/gray74" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

**First:** A `MenuItem` is not a `View` and consequently it's not part of your layout. Therefore you shouldn't be using:

```
MenuItem searchBar = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.search);
```

But instead:

```
MenuItem searchBar = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
```

**Second:** When you make changes to your menu, you should call [invalidateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29).

By doing this you basically tell the menu that some changes have been made to it. This will make the menu recreate itself and request that the system call [onPrepareOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).